# IIS7.5 Server - No sites running but returns 404

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have two sites stopped in IIS7.5.  Whenever I make a request to the site it allows the connection and returns HTTP Status 404 with the following message.

Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Is there a way to ensure that IIS stops listening and doesn't reply to the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check and see if any other services or applications are listening to port 80. Maybe something else is answering and it's not either of your IIS sites after all. Weird though.

Comment: Turns out the deployment service was still responding to port 80 requests.  Thanks for the tip!